# Create discrete colour axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, color-scheme, ggmap

I am plotting concentration data on a map, my data looks like this:

```
   Lat         Long         Conc        Colour
-33.90624     151.2237       10.0        #4393C3
-33.92404     151.2280       12.95       #92C5DE
-33.92384     151.2275       14.0        #D1E5F0
```

Plotting on the map using:

```
map <- ggmap(map)+ 
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(151.220, 151.230), expand = c(0, 0)) +
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-33.927, -33.902), expand = c(0, 0))

map + 
   geom_point(data = df_avg, aes(x = df_avg$Long, y = df_avg$Lat), 
       col = df_avg$Colour, cex = 4.2) + 
   ggtitle(paste0("PM2.5 (ug/m3)", "    ", title_start,"  -  ", title_end))
```

The colour scale I am using is: (the "RdBu" RColorBrewer palette)

```
"#67001F" "#B2182B" "#D6604D" "#F4A582" "#FDDBC7" 
   "#F7F7F7" "#D1E5F0" "#92C5DE" "#4393C3" "#2166AC" "#053061"
```

I would like to add a labelled colour axis on the side of my map with discrete squares. Can anyone help me with this?

I have attached [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYYgk.jpg) of what I am thinking of - this was taken from [R ggplot2 discrete colour palette for gradient map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336012/r-ggplot2-discrete-colour-palette-for-gradient-map) (this question didn't help me sadly as I am using `ggmap`)

Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend letting `ggplot()` do the aesthetic mapping for you: since you have done the mapping yourself (I'm assuming some sort `Conc -> Colour` mapping here?) **ggplot2** can't automatically generate a legend for you.

Comment: Look at scale_fill_manual()

Answer (score 1):

You should let `ggplot` do the color mapping for you as @MikkoMartillia suggested. Then you get an automatic legend. Below I created a reproducible example from your data. First I added the color labels to the data. Then I basically used your code to create the plot, but moved the color inside the `aes` call. Finally I added a color scale with the `"RdBu"` palette and the correct limits.

```
# import packages
require(tibble)
require(dplyr)
require(ggmap)
require(RColorBrewer)

# load data
df_avg <- tribble(~Lat, ~Long, ~Conc, ~Colour,
                  -33.90624, 151.2237, 10.0, "#4393C3",
                  -33.92404, 151.2280, 12.95, "#92C5DE",
                  -33.92384, 151.2275, 14.0, "#D1E5F0")

# add colour to data
df_labels <- tibble(label = letters[1:11], # change this to sensible labels
                    Colour = brewer.pal(11,  "RdBu"))
df_avg <- left_join(df_avg, df_labels)

# download map
map <- get_map(location = c(lon = 151.225, lat = -33.913), zoom = 14)
# map plot
p_map <- ggmap(map)+ 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(151.220, 151.230), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-33.927, -33.902), expand = c(0, 0))
# add points to map
p_map + 
  geom_point(data = df_avg, aes(x = Long, y = Lat, color = label), cex = 4.2) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdBu", limits = df_labels$label)
```

Comment: Hi Shadow, thanks for your reply :) What does this part mean? 
    label = letters[1:11]

Having trouble getting this to work for my larger dataset

Comment: These are the labels that you want to use for the colors. I.e. `a` corresponds to color `"#67001F"`, `b` corresponds to `"#B2182B"` and so forth.